# How to get transaction hash of a function call from web3?

Tags: web3js

Lets say I use web3 to call foo.bar() like so:

```
var foo = await Foo.deployed();
var result = await foo.bar();
```

If I `console.log(result)` I just see something that says `[Object object]`

How can I get the transaction hash of the function call? I'd like to be able to keep track of its status. e.g. failed, pending etc.

Thanks!

Comment: to inspect an object in the console use `console.dir(result);` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends if you are using the new beta version of web3.js 1.0 or the older 0.x version:

from the web3 1.0 beta [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send):

```
myContract.methods.myMethod(123).send({from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe'})
    .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
        console.log(hash);
})
```

in web3 0.x you can see [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods) how to call a smart contract function and then look [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) for the return value:

```
var txHash = myContractInstance.myMethod(param1, param2);
console.log(txHash);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `signedTransaction` object, you can run

```
var transactionHash = web3.utils.sha3(signedTx, { encoding: "hex" });
```

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html?highlight=utils#sha3
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#signtransaction